# Python: Looping If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

```
friends = ["Bob","Mike","Ana","Tim","Dog"]

def is_buddy(name):

    for friend in friends:
        print friend
        if friend == name:
            return True
        else:
            return

print (is_buddy('Tim'))
```

What is the problem here? Why do I get `False` if I put in "Tim" or anyone else other than Bob?

Comment: Impossible. From your code you can't get `False`

Comment: You'll get `None`, not `False`, with the code as posted.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def is_buddy(name):
    for friend in friends:
        if friend == name:
            return True
    return False
```

The problem is that you checked `name` against the first entry of the list which is `Bob` and you decided to make a boolean decision. You should have returned `False` only at the end where you checked against every element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way to do what you want:

```
friends = ["Bob","Mike","Ana","Tim","Dog"]

def is_buddy(name):
    if name in friends:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print (is_buddy('Tim'))
```

Comment: If we're trying to be Pythonic, you could write `return name in friends`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `else` statement tigers `return` which causes the end of the for loop after 1'st iteration

What you probably want to do is to continue looping. So just remove `else` part from your function or replace `return` with something like `print "not found"`